# Not In Where condition in SAS Hive Hadoop removing blanks

Tags: hadoop, hive, sas, hiveql

I'm hoping someone has come across this!

I've noticed when using 'Not In' where condition in SAS Hadoop (explicit SQL Pass through) it will remove blanks in the field it relates to (the REASON field).

If using 'standard' Proc SQL it only remove what is stated and not blanks.

Is there a workaround to this so I can keep the blanks?

Example code:

```
    Create Table TEST_02 As
    Select
     a.*
    ,b.Info
    ,b.Info2

    From TEST_01 a

    Left Join TEST_03 b
    ON a.SERVICE = b.SERVICE

    Where a.REASON Not In ('REASON1', 'REASON2', 'REASON3')
    And a.ACTIVITY Not In ('ACTIVITY1','ACTIVITY2')
    And a.e_date >= >= '2018-01-01'
```

Comment: if possible can you write the sample code and do you want blanks to be removed or not.

Comment: Hi..... I've added example code (excluding connecting to Hive bits).....I will need blanks including in final output

Comment: Are you very similar query in SAS? By blanks you mean where there is no service to service match, even though you are using left join, I see you are using where clause, which might be making it close to an Inner join. try changing where to and and see what difference it brings

Comment: To clarify there are blanks in the REASON field, those I want to keep as well...... I'm not sure what you mean by "changing where to and" ?

Comment: I am  thinking probably youare removing null reason in query probably suing where activity not in and by using date  conditions. If I were you I will try modifying your acitivity and end date logic and check what is happening. If you can show us sample data from both the tables, someone can help you

Comment: Are what you call blanks (and see as blanks when viewed in SAS) actually null values in the remote side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this variation

```
( a.REASON Not In ('REASON1', 'REASON2', 'REASON3') or a.REASON IS NULL )
and
( a.ACTIVITY Not In ('ACTIVITY1','ACTIVITY2') or a.ACTIVITY IS NULL )
```

Comment: Looks like that has done the job, thank you Richard.

Comment: Great! Be sure to [mark answers to your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)